# MySQL Workbench acquire access for administration?

Tags: mysql, sql

Вылазит такая ошибка:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я сделал всё то, что там написано:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но всё равно это не помогло. Я облазил инет, всё, что смог найти попробовал, но всё равно ничего не помогло.

Comment: в англо язычно версии уже сталкивались и решили эту проблему, вот Вам ссылка : [тык сюда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53236494/could-not-acquire-management-access-for-administration-runtime-error-unable-to)

Comment: Найдите на СВОЁМ компе файл `chcp.exe`. Для 64-битной Windows - см. в каталоге `C:\Windows\SysWOW64`. Именно каталог с этим файлом должен присутствовать в PATH.

Answer (score 7):

Всем привет.
Тоже долго гуглил тему. Ваш топик помог разобраться. В "англоязычной версии" предлагают сделать дичь - заменить один системный файл другим. И это при том, что у них битность разная.
Папка "C:\Windows\System32" изначально присутствует в path, в системных переменных среды. Повсеместный совет с ее добавлением через 10 минут поисков аж бесить начал, своей бесполезностью и тупостью.
Добавление в path папки C:\Windows\SysWOW64 тоже не помогает - procmon показывает, что Workbench все равно, запускает эту программу из system32, а не из SysWOW64.
Мне помогло копирование двух файлов (Windows 10 Home x64):
c:\Windows\SysWOW64\chcp.com
c:\Windows\SysWOW64\ulib.dll
В папку с программой:
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 8.0

Comment: Помогло, спасибо + ^